# Are there any robot that working with ROS Kinetic? (not turtlebot)

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Kinetic Kame version is released on
> last year (May 23rd, 2016).

( *It is 301 days from the start date to today's date* :) )

But still I can't find any robots that fully working with Kinetic version :(

Are there any?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257739/are-there-any-robot-that-working-with-ros-kinetic?-(not-turtlebot)/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I found simple one :D

[**ROBOTIS - TurtleBot3**](http://turtlebot3.robotis.com)

**The steps below works fine now, anyway they can be improve or change the repositories. I definitely suggest to follow the link above.**

The Tutorials teaches installation but There is a big `<TODO>` under Gazebo section. Coincidentally I saw the other branch and so, I cloned `develop` branch :)

First:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard ros-kinetic-laser-proc ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino ros-kinetic-rosserial-python ros-kinetic-rosserial-server ros-kinetic-rosserial-client ros-kinetic-rosserial-msgs ros-kinetic-amcl ros-kinetic-map-server ros-kinetic-move-base ros-kinetic-hls-lfcd-lds-driver ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-xacro ros-kinetic-gmapping ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop
```

Then:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone -b develop https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git
sed -i 's/isnan/std::isnan/g' `grep "isnan" -rl` #May be you can get error when compiling without this
cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make && source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

And Finally:

```
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger && roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_gazebo.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2017-03-25**:
Hi Orhan, do you know a robotics arm to simulate it in gazebo(I'm using kinetic too) ..?

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2017-03-26**:
Hi, no, but I suggest, If you have a robotic arm which works with old versions, run it via older way, then look at errors, try to solve them.